# Captcha is not working as expected.Visible on webform when logged out and invisible when logged in

Tags: captcha

[image: Before login]

[image: After login]

I have not selected any of the options:

1. Default challenge on non-listed forms.
2. Add CAPTCHA administration links to forms
3. Allow CAPTCHAs and CAPTCHA administration links on administrative pages

I have selected persistence:
Omit challenges in a multi-step/preview workflow once the user successfully responds to a challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is expected behaviour. Under permissions there is an option:

> Skip CAPTCHA
>
> Users with this permission will not be offered a CAPTCHA.

Admin by default has this set meaning they won't see the Captcha. Captcha isn't necessary for an Admin since they are assumed to be trustworthy.

You can also set other roles here so that they don't see the Captcha. If you have strong Bot deterrents in user registration, you probably don't want authenticated users to have to go through the Captcha process after every node/comment/etc creation as this will just cause annoyance, especially for regular contributors. If you allow anonymous content creation, obviously you don't want to provide this option for that role, or the Bots will come knocking...